# How to add ipv6 default route

Tags: ipv6, route

I have the following setup

```
           Linux 1                      Linux 0
    eth1            eth0-------------------eth0
   14.14.14.80      19.19.19.20             19.19.19.10
   2005::5/64       2004::3/64              2001::3/64
```

From Linux0, i am able to ping `14.14.14.80 or 19.19.19.20` ( `19.19.19.20` was added as a default GW) and also on `Linux1`, `ipv4` forwarding was enabled.
For `ipv6`, i cannot add `2004::3/64` as the default ipv6 gateway on `Linux0`.
I tried

```
ip -6 route add default via 2004::3
```

and

```
ip -6 route add default via 2004::
```

But i get the error

```
RTNETLINK answers: No route to host
```

What am i missing here?.

Comment: Add the network mask to the above line: ip -6 route add 2004::/64 dev eth0

Comment: The normal thing to do would be to put devices on the same ethernet network in the same subnet, then you wouldn't have this problem.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You need to add the route to the gateway first:

```
ip -6 route add 2004::3 dev eth0
```

Answer (score 8):

To add a default gateway, and not one specific to an Ethernet interface (dev), use:

```
route add default gw <GW IP Address> # For IPv4
route add -A inet6 default gw <GW IP Address> # For IPv6; you must specify the Address Family (AF)
```

Notice, you don't have to specify the subnet mask, nor the outgoing Ethernet interface.

To verify your work, list the host's IP routing table suing:

```
netstat -rn # for IPv4
netstat -rn -A inet6  # for IPv6
```